# Python BeautifulSoup get text from class

Tags: beautifulsoup, get, python-requests

How can I get the text "Lionel Messi" from this HTML code?

`<a href="/20/player/44079/lionel-messi" class="player_name_players_table">Lionel Messi</a>`

This is my code so far:

```
import requests
import urllib.request
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = requests.get('https://www.futbin.com/players')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'lxml')

pool = soup.find(id='repTb')


player_names = pool.find_all(class_='player_name_players_table')


print(player_names[0])
```

When I print player_names I get this result:

```
/Users/ejps/PycharmProjects/scraper_players/venv/bin/python /Users/ejps/PycharmProjects/scraper_players/scraper.py
<a class="player_name_players_table" href="/20/player/44079/lionel-messi">Lionel Messi</a>

Process finished with exit code 0
```

But what code would I have to put in to get only the text of it?

I want to scrape all player names form that page in my code. But first I need to find a way to get that text extracted I think.

Cant find a way to make it work unfortunately.

I am new to python and try to do some projects to learn it.

**EDIT:**

With the help from comments I was able to get the text I need.

I only have one more question here.

Is it possible to find class_ by partial text only?

Like this:

```
prating = pool.find_all(class_='form rating ut20')
```

The full class would be

```
class="form rating ut20 toty gold rare"
```

but it is changing. The part that is always the same is "form rating ut20" so I thought maybe there is some kind of a placeholder that let me search for all "class" names inlcuding "form rating ut20"

Could you maybe help me with this as well?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [BeautifulSoup getText from between <p>, not picking up subsequent paragraphs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12451997/beautifulsoup-gettext-from-between-p-not-picking-up-subsequent-paragraphs), https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38133759/how-to-get-text-from-span-tag-in-beautifulsoup

Comment: You should split this into two different questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To select specific class you can use either **regular expression** or if you have installed version **bs4 4.7.1** or above you can use **css** selector.

Using `regular expression` will get list of element.

```
import re
prating = pool.find_all(class_=re.compile("form rating ut20"))
```

---

Or Using css selector will get list of element.1st css selector means contains and other one means starts-with.

```
prating = pool.select('[class*="form rating ut20"]')
```

OR

```
prating = pool.select('[class^="form rating ut20"]')
```

Answer (score 1):

Get text using the getText() method.

```
 player_names[0].getText()
```

Comment: giving me this error: 
AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'getText'. You're probably treating a list of elements like a single element. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: You are trying to call the getText() on  a list. Make sure you call getText() on a single item from the list.

Comment: import requests
import urllib.request
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = requests.get('https://www.futbin.com/players')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'lxml')

pool = soup.find(id='repTb')


player_names = pool.find_all(class_='player_name_players_table')


print(player_names[0].getText())

Comment: If you want to get the list of all player names: [player_names[i].getText() for i in range(0,len(player_names))]

Comment: Also, if you found this answer useful please upvote it. Thanks

Comment: thanks that helped! Do you also have an Idea for my EDIT maybe?

Comment: Yes, you can use regex