# How to extract text in opening and closing html tags using BeautifulSoup python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Hi There,

```
<p>
Hello There This is some text
<br>
<em class="long-content string">9638</em></p>
```

I want to extract 9638 from above html code
I try:

```
soup.find("em", attrs={"class":"long-content string"})
```

ouput:

```
<em class="long-content string">9638</em>
```

How we can extract 9638

Thanks:

Comment: Have you refer documentation??

Comment: Yes but there is no solution I tried many times

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comment, from the documentation

> If you want to search for tags that match two or more CSS classes, you should use a CSS selector:

so

```py
elements = soup.select("em.long-content.string")
```

for getting the content of the tag see https://stackoverflow.com/a/13087415/10163723

Answer (score 0):

You should access the attribute `text`, e.g:
`soup.find("em", attrs={"class":"long-content string"}).text`

EDIT: I also suggest filtering in a different way (using `select` as suggested in other answers)