# How to get text from a <p> with a 'style' attribute?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm using BeautifulSoup and I would like to know how I can get the value $45.00 from this HTML path?

```html
<p style="color: rgb(153, 153, 153); margin-bottom: 0px; font-size: 12px;" data-open-accessibility-text-original="12px">
     $45.00        
</p>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [BeautifulSoup getText from between <p>, not picking up subsequent paragraphs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12451997/beautifulsoup-gettext-from-between-p-not-picking-up-subsequent-paragraphs)

Answer (score 0):

hello [html2text](https://github.com/Alir3z4/html2text) is a Python script that does a good job at this.