# How do I further scrape the string from an extracted element in html using python?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

```
counter=0
for col in soup.find(class_='m-nktq8b'):
    if counter==0:
        counter+=1
        continue
    else:
        print(col)
        print(col['class'])
```

Above is my input, and below is my output:

```
<p class="m-1nj5h5j">Severe</p>

['m-1nj5h5j']
```

How could I further scrape the word between > and <, which is 'Severe'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can extract this using [regex](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html):

```py
import re

text = '<p class="m-1nj5h5j">Severe</p>'

print(re.search(r'<p .+?>(.+)</p>', text).group(1))
```

Output is:

```
Severe
```

However, it looks more like a work-around than a solution. A better solution is to extract this using just [beautifulsoup's `find`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find):

```
counter = 0
for col in soup.find(class_="m-nktq8b"):
    if counter == 0:
        counter += 1
        continue
    else:
        # here is the line:
        print(col.find("p"))
```

Checkout [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12451997/beautifulsoup-gettext-from-between-p-not-picking-up-subsequent-paragraphs) for more information.